# How to link to JDK?

Tags: java, scala, scaladoc

I want to have links like

- Javadoc `{@link Object#toString()}`
- Scaladoc `[[Object#toString()]]`

How can I do this with scaladoc?

I assume I'll have to provide the external URL to link to.

Comment: Scaladoc, in particular, is picky about using fully qualified paths inside [[]]. Try `java.lang.Object.toString` instead.